# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL

Tags: mongodb, nestjs

I have clone a nestjs project and run by using `npm start`.
I got below error.

I am new to nestjs. Please help me to find the error

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:363:5)
    at onParseError (node:internal/url:537:9)
    at new URL (node:internal/url:613:5)
    at new HostAddress (/advice/node_modules/mongodb/src/utils.ts:1322:32)
    at fromString (/advice/node_modules/mongodb/src/utils.ts:1369:12)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object.parseOptions (/advice/node_modules/mongodb/src/connection_string.ts:253:43)
    at new MongoClient (/advice/node_modules/mongodb/src/mongo_client.ts:332:22)
    at advice/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:785:16
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
```

Edit:
**Answer**

Have create a file .env
with

```
DB_USERNAME=username
DB_PASSWORD=pw
DB_DATABASE=db
DB_HOST=host
DB_PORT=port
```

Comment: What are you passing to the `mongoose` library?

Comment: You mean, this ` MongooseModule.forRoot(
      `mongodb://${process.env.DB_USERNAME}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}@${process.env.DB_HOST}:${process.env.DB_PORT}`,
      {
        dbName: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
      },
    ),`

Comment: How do you populate `process.env`?

Comment: There is a file named as `env.example` with `DB_USERNAME=
DB_PASSWORD=
DB_DATABASE=
DB_HOST=
DB_PORT=` this code

Comment: Okay, but how does that file get its values transferred into the node process?

Comment: By importing, `
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';`  and `imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      cache: true,
    }),....]`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Nest's `@nestjs/config` module for populating from an `.env` file, you should be using the [async registration method](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb#async-configuration) like so:

```js
MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
    uri: configService.get<string>('MONGODB_URI'),
  }),
  inject: [ConfigService],
});
```